# Integration DoctrineExtensions-Taggable into Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-extensions

How can I integrate [DoctrineExtensions-Taggable](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable) into Zend Framework2 ?

I added to my composer file.

```
"fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable": "dev-master",
```

Then added listener to EventManager

```
'eventmanager' => array(
     'orm_default' => array(
          'subscribers' => array(
               'DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagListener',
          ),
     ),
),
```

Now I have error like 
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/html/fryday/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php on line 135